# Installing nm-connection-editor on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dependencies

So I found out that my installation of Ubuntu doesn't have nm-connection-editor. I tried installing it but it said package not found. After a bit of searching I came across that I will have to install `network-manager-gnome` for that. I tried installing it and I got this issue:

```
$ sudo apt install network-manager-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager-gnome : Depends: libnma0 (= 1.8.24-1ubuntu2) but 1.8.24-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
                         Recommends: mobile-broadband-provider-info but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried using `sudo apt install -f network-manager-gnome` but it did not work. I would appreciate some help regarding this.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or a Ubuntu 20.04 based system?  The package `network-manager-gnome` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/network-manager-gnome) on an updated 20.04 system does **not** have a *depends* rule for the version you specify, but instead "*libnma0 (= 1.8.24-1ubuntu3)*" so you're likely not using Ubuntu 20.04 or are sourcing that package from a non-Ubuntu source, thus its a source issue.   Start with `sudo apt update` & read the output, any warnings, missing lines, errors etc?  It'd be helpful to if you were specific; Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop? Ubuntu 20.04 Server? etc